# Multilevel Modelling , 2 level -statistical significance test on random effects

Tags: r, statistical-significance, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I have fitted two-level MLM for synthetic data. I have fitted the model using lme4 package and also imported lmerTest for the statistical significance test of fixed effects. But I am unable to do statistical significance tests on the random effects. I am new to this model and still exploring how MLM works.

a snippet of the code I am using

```
library(lmerTest)
library(lme4)

modelC <- lmer(Y ~ P1*Time+ (Time|ID), data = dataset, REML = FALSE)
summary(modelC)
```

If anyone can help/guide me with this it will be really helpful. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the site, Zubaer. There is no equivalent significance test for random effects as there are for fixed effects. Instead, you can run model comparison tests, in which you run a likelihood ratio test on nested models. In your case, you can run the following model, call it `modelC0`:

`modelC0 <- lmer(Y ~ P1*Time + (1|ID), data = dataset, REML=FALSE)`

Notice that this model differs in that it does not have a random slope for Time. Thus one can get from `modelC` to `modelC0` by constraining the slope variance and slope-intercept co-variance to 0. The models differ by two degrees of freedom. The likelihood ratio test, `anova(modelC, modelC0)`, which is $\chi^2$-distributed, is a test of whether the increased complexity of `modelC` provides a better fit to the data (significant p-value) or is no better (non-significant p-value). If it is not a better fit, one can move forward with `modelC0` as their target model.

This is how one goes about testing random effects in mixed models.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, can you please elaborate what does 2 -distributed means here? In the output of ANOVA, I can see the Chisq, but I don't know how to interpret it. thank you.

Comment: It means that the difference in log-likelihoods follows a $\chi^2$ distribution. Hence, the likelihood ratio test uses a $\chi^2$ test with associated degrees of freedom (two in your case) to determine significance. In the `anova` output, the p-value shows up as `Pr(>Chisq)`. If that is less than .05, this is typically viewed as statistically significant.